# Citation undefined OverLeaf - Reference Manager Zotero Linked

Tags: latex, bibtex, bibliography, overleaf

I am trying to cite some articles, but I get this this output "[?]" on the PDF.

My references are linked through Zotero through the "MyLibraryZotero.bib" file and link

These are some of the references that are giving this error:

```
@misc{xie_efficient_2021,
    title = {An efficient casting methodology for contactless evaluation of neocartilage formation in vitro},
    publisher = {The University of Melbourne},
    author = {Xie, Amy},
    year = {2021},
}
```

**ERROR: Citation `xie_efficient_2021' on page 79 undefined on input line 28. You have cited something which is not included in your bibliography. Make sure that the citation (\cite{...}) has a corresponding key in your bibliography, and that both are spelled the same way.**

```
@article{ruland_quantitative_2019,
    title = {Quantitative ultrasound imaging of cell-laden hydrogels and printed constructs},
    volume = {91},
    issn = {1742-7061},
    url = {https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1742706119302983},
    doi = {10.1016/j.actbio.2019.04.055},
    language = {en},
    urldate = {2023-05-19},
    journal = {Acta Biomaterialia},
    author = {Ruland, Andres and Gilmore, Kerry J. and Daikuara, Luciana Y. and Fay, Cormac D. and Yue, Zhilian and Wallace, Gordon G.},
    month = jun,
    year = {2019},
    keywords = {MechTesting, US Elastography, Unread, notion},
    pages = {173--185},
}

@article{ruland_reference_2021,
    title = {Reference phantom method for ultrasonic imaging of thin dynamic constructs},
    volume = {47},
    issn = {0301-5629, 1879-291X},
    url = {https://www.umbjournal.org/article/S0301-5629(21)00193-9/fulltext},
    doi = {10.1016/j.ultrasmedbio.2021.04.014},
    language = {English},
    number = {8},
    urldate = {2024-01-25},
    journal = {Ultrasound in Medicine and Biology},
    author = {Ruland, Andres and Hill, James M. and Wallace, Gordon G.},
    month = aug,
    year = {2021},
    pmid = {34059374},
    note = {Publisher: Elsevier},
    keywords = {US Elastography, notion},
    pages = {2388--2403},
}
```

This is how I have referenced them in the document:
"path respectively \cite{ruland_reference_2021}."

"which aligns with the literature \cite{rice_ultrasound_2009,ruland_quantitative_2019}. "

"previous studies \cite{xie_efficient_2021}"

Does anyone know why these specific references arent working?

I use also these lines to introduce the bibliography:

```
\bibliographystyle{IEEEtran}
\bibliography{MyLibraryZotero}
```

EDIT:

Here is a reference that does work:

```
@article{statham_reproducing_2022,
    title = {Reproducing the {Biomechanical} {Environment} of the {Chondrocyte} for {Cartilage} {Tissue} {Engineering}},
    volume = {28},
    issn = {1937-3368},
    url = {https://www.liebertpub.com/doi/full/10.1089/ten.teb.2020.0373},
    doi = {10.1089/ten.teb.2020.0373},
    abstract = {It is well known that the biomechanical and tribological performance of articular cartilage is inextricably linked to its extracellular matrix (ECM) structure and zonal heterogeneity. Furthermore, it is understood that the presence of native ECM components, such as collagen II and aggrecan, promote healthy homeostasis in the resident chondrocytes. What is less frequently discussed is how chondrocyte metabolism is related to the extracellular mechanical environment, at both the macro and microscale. The chondrocyte is in immediate contact with the pericellular matrix of the chondron, which acts as a mechanocoupler, transmitting external applied loads from the ECM to the chondrocyte. Therefore, components of the pericellular matrix also play essential roles in chondrocyte mechanotransduction and metabolism. Recreating the biomechanical environment through tuning material properties of a scaffold and/or the use of external cyclic loading can induce biosynthetic responses in chondrocytes. Decellularized scaffolds, which retain the native tissue macro- and microstructure also represent an effective means of recapitulating such an environment. The use of such techniques in tissue engineering applications can ensure the regeneration of skeletally mature articular cartilage with appropriate biomechanical and tribological properties to restore joint function. Despite the pivotal role in graft maturation and performance, biomechanical and tribological properties of such interventions is often underrepresented. This review outlines the role of biomechanics in relation to native cartilage performance and chondrocyte metabolism, and how application of this theory can enhance the future development and successful translation of biomechanically relevant tissue engineering interventions.

Impact statement

Physiological cartilage function is a key criterion in the success of a cartilage tissue engineering solution. The in situ performance is dependent on the initial scaffold design as well as extracellular matrix deposition by endogenous or exogenous cells. Both biological and biomechanical stimuli serve as key regulators of cartilage homeostasis and maturation of the resulting tissue-engineered graft. An improved understanding of the influence of biomechanics on cellular function and consideration of the final biomechanical and tribological performance will help in the successful development and translation of tissue-engineered grafts to restore natural joint function postcartilage trauma or osteoarthritic degeneration, delaying the requirement for prosthetic intervention.},
    number = {2},
    urldate = {2023-04-12},
    journal = {Tissue Engineering Part B: Reviews},
    author = {Statham, Patrick and Jones, Elena and Jennings, Louise M. and Fermor, Hazel L.},
    month = apr,
    year = {2022},
    note = {Publisher: Mary Ann Liebert, Inc., publishers},
    keywords = {Biofabrication, MechProp Cart, MechTesting, notion},
    pages = {405--420},
}
```

and how it is cited in my work:

"...articulating ends of bones at the joint \cite{statham_reproducing_2022}"

Comment: In your example, the ruland references are missing closing brackets. It is probably not like that in your setup, but it does make it harder to help you

Comment: A [minimal reproducible example|https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example] may be helpful. That would be something like a small TeX document with the needed imports and a cite that works and one that doesn't. This would help us to reproduce your problem and help you. The code snippets provided are not as helpful.

Comment: Yes sorry, there are brackets in my linked zotero bib file. Please see my edits to see a cite that does work